# SAAS Application Architecture Microservices vs Monolithic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microservices, multi-tenant, saas

We are building an app for ecommerce sellers to visualise their data in a graphical manner from sales, advertising campaigns & some other metrics. I can break app components in three different parts:

1. An app where user creates personalise dashboard with different
   metric's graph. User is able to apply advance filters to the data &
   visualise data filtered data on graphs.
2. A set of background jobs which will fetch the data from third
   party APIs of different platforms. Jobs has to be scheduled on
   weekly basis, daily basis, hourly basis depends on Job type. The
   data volume will be high as we gonna build it as a SAAS platform.
3. Some of the data is not available via API, so we have to run
   some automation tasks(crawlers) to manually download it, for the
   user(may be using selenium).

We have partially built the first part in **Ruby on Rails**.

We need suggestions to make architectural decisions to start development, questions:

- Microservices Architecture or monolithic?
- Should we built background jobs system in Rails using ActiveJob with some queuing library or some third party background jobs handler? Background jobs will include massive API calls. The architecture is multi-tenant & will be being used by multiple sellers.
- If we choose to use Microservices Architecture, what should be the communication medium between micro apps?:
- Shared db across micro apps?
- Whenever we need to process an operation, i.e start a job, should we do it via http call to that service, or is there a better communication medium?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: This is depends on how big is a team. If team is small and wanna goto production fast always pick "Monolithic". If its high traffic API's with background jobs. Go for serverless function or make own background jobs engine in separate instance like only for job handling.

Answer (score 2):

Monolithic vs Microservices :

the better option is **definitely microservices**. with microservices you can get at least the following benefits:

- independently deployable services
- using different technologies for each service
- deploying each part with different configs
- host your heavy load worker services in separate servers
- recover failures rapidly without affecting other parts
- do a cloud-friendly design
- scale fast and affordable

**Design** needs insight and teamwork. As a raw solution I suggest:

- use a single service that routes external requests to your system and acts as an API gateway. Nginx is a good choice.
- all other services should only be accessed internally.
- for communication between services, you can expose a rest-API for each or
- employ a message broker.

I suggest RabbitMQ (Kafka in some cases is more suitable). each service subscribes to few channels in message broker. when a related event like "URL inserted" is received, it defines a new task for itself and starts processing a job (for example crawling the website at that URL). after that it can send a new event to the broker like "website processed" and so other services will be informed while each knows what to do after.

- the service that is responsible for responding to the user, when receiving a request needing to do a long-running job, notifies other services via their API or sends a new event and related data to the broker and after that responses the success message to the user.
- services can start new tasks after new events or according to a schedule.

**Some hints:**

- use containerization with something like Docker. when doing so, you can use tools like docker swarm or Kubernetes. they give you invaluable benefits:

  - simple maintenance
  - high availability
  - fast scaling
  - scaling automatically on demand
  - scaling each micro-service independently
  - service discovery. no need to hardcode location of services
  - circuit-breaker to prevent repeating request to dead services and cut waiting times.
- with microservices, you can choose between choreography and orchestration patterns. use choreography.
- use CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) pattern to have different DBs for CRUD operations and reporting

**To answer your questions**:

- Microservices Architecture or monolithic?

  - answer: microservices
- Should we built background jobs system in Rails using....?

  - answer: you can use different technologies and designs for each service
- Background jobs will include massive API calls...?

  - answer: you can scale each micro-service independently as demand even dynamically.
- what should be the communication medium between micro apps?

  - answer: rest API, message broker or mixed
- Shared DB across micro apps?

  - answer: each domain is better to have its own DB. but it's per domain, not per worker. you can have one main DB shared by related workers. but for other domains like users you better to have different dbs.
- Whenever we need to process an operation....?

  - answer: some services can be scheduled to act like Cron jobs. there may be other jobs in the process flow that will be triggered by user requests asynchronously.